# Storing new object in pointer vector c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

With the following code i need to store new object in pointer vector. I've done it but now it wont show any information about object in loop (where I go trough vector). In class Tvrtka (company) I have pointer vector of Zaposlenik(worker). For every object I store it goes to vector.

```
class Tvrtka{
public:
    string oib;
    string naziv;
    string adresa;
    vector<const Zaposlenik*> zaposlenici;
    Tvrtka(){}
    Tvrtka(const string _oib, const string _naziv,const  string _adresa, vector<const Zaposlenik*> _z)

    {
        this->oib=_oib;
        this->naziv=_naziv;
        this->adresa=_adresa;
        for(int i=0;_z.size();i++)
        {
            zaposlenici.push_back(_z[i]);
        }
    }
```

Main part:

```
vector<const Zaposlenik*>zaposlenici;

    Zaposlenik *z1=new Zaposlenik("Marko", "maric", 20);
    zaposlenici.push_back(z1);

    Tvrtka t1("198","Majur", "2222", zaposlenici);


        for(int i=0;i<zaposlenici.size();i++)
        {


            cout<<zaposlenici[i]->ime;
        }
```

If I comment t1(object of Tvrtka) it shows me information about worker.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve], expected behavior and what you got instead.

Comment: Note loop in `Tvrtka` ctor is completely redundant, copy ctor of the vector (or assignment) would lead to exactly the same result.

Comment: Rollbacked because this version is nearer to complete (not complete though)

Comment: @MikeCAT by rollback you invalidated you answer :)

Comment: @Slava What do you mean?

Comment: @MikeCAT nevermind, I thought that loop is correct now, it is really easy to see it that way

Comment: Avoid owning bare pointers. Also avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Comment: Can u give me example of bare pointers.

Comment: The constructor can be written much more simply with a constructor initializer list: `Tvrtka(const string _oib, const string _naziv,const  string _adresa, vector<const Zaposlenik*> _z) : oib(_oib), naziv(_naziv), adresa(_adresa), zaposlenici(_z) { }`.

Comment: Somethimes I write it like that but this time I used pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(int i=0;_z.size();i++)
{
    zaposlenici.push_back(_z[i]);
}
```

`_z.size()` is used as loop condition and this is not dependent with `i`.
This means that if you pass non-empty vector as `_z`, the loop will go infinitely and it will run out of memory.

It should be

```
for(int i=0;i<_z.size();i++)
{
    zaposlenici.push_back(_z[i]);
}
```

or simply

```
for(auto& elem : _z)
{
    zaposlenici.push_back(elem);
}
```

Comment: Or simply `zaposlenici = _z;`

Comment: My mistake with condition, tnx guys. it's i<_z, I did not see it

Comment: @Momo that's why it is better not to write redundant code, less chances to create a mistake.